# Поиск подстроки в строке с помощью preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно искать в пакете:

```
private [3OHA SCANNER] Shet
```

Возможно я не так что-то экранировал

```
if (preg_match ( "/private \[3OHA SCANNER]\Shet/U" , $buf )) {
        fputs ( $klient, "<NOF war_list=\"1\" />\r\n\r\n" );
        $Schet = fgets ( $klient );
        fputs($chat, "<POST t=\"private [clan]Shet:${Shet}\" />\r\n\r\n");
      } 
}
```

Comment: если у вас фиксированная строка, то вам не нужны регулярки вообще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам всего лишь надо внимательнее следить за пробелами и размещением слеша. Скопируйте свою строку в preg_match и поставьте обратные слеши перед квадратными скобками.

```
preg_match("/private \[3OHA SCANNER\] Shet/U", $buf)
```

Вам нужен "нежадный поиск"? Если так, то ок, а если вы хотели указать на Unicode, то модификатор нужен в нижнем регистре: "/blablabla/u"

Comment: спасибо , значит у меня по прежнему ошибка в другом месте наверно)

Comment: потому что условие срабатывает хотя в чат не писали слово Shet

Comment: В php (а возможно и не только здесь), при работе с регулярками вся строка проходит два цикла разбора: первый раз строка парсится самим php, а второй раз уже обработанная строка парсится механизмом регулярок. Поэтому лучше привыкнуть сразу экранировать обратный слеш. Да, сейчас работать будет и с одним, но что если вместо `[...]` будет использоваться ` \...\ `?